# How can I update a scope variable passed in as an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that updates a scope variable whenever the element's scrollTop changes. With this directive I'm hoping to be able to sync the scroll positions of two different elements.

Here's what I have so far:

```
module.directive('scrollTop', [function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var scrollTop = $scope.$eval(attrs.scrollTop);

            element.bind('scroll', function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    scrollTop = element.prop('scrollTop');
                    console.log("scrollTop", scrollTop);
                });
            });

            attrs.$observe('scrollTop', function(value){
                console.log('detected change', value);
                element.prop('scrollTop', value);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and here's part of the Karma test I'm writing for it:

```
it('scrolls', function() {
        var element = angular.element('<div scroll-top="scrollTopScopeVar" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;"><div style="height: 200px;"></div></div>');
        $compile(element)($scope);
        element.appendTo(document.body);
        $scope.$digest();

        element.prop('scrollTop', 42);
        element.trigger('scroll');

        expect($scope.scrollTopScopeVar).toBe(42);
    });
```

The problem is that the scrollTop variable that is being passed in (scrollTopScopeVar) is never updated. I'm pretty sure my problem is that I'm only updating my reference to that variable and not actually changing the value, but I'm not sure how else to go about changing it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh DUH, super simple answer here. All I need to do is access the scope directly and change the variable there:

```
element.bind('scroll', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope[attrs.scrollTop] = element.prop('scrollTop');  //DUH
        console.log("scrollTop", $scope[attrs.scrollTop]);
    });
});
```